# Question related to the teb local planner tutorial

Tags: ros, teb-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I have encounter some problem during the tutorial in the teb_local_planner tutorial (http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner/Tutorials/Following%20the%20Global%20Plan%20%28Via-Points%29), in part 2 Optimization with via-point, I was trying to find the  *global_plan_viapoint_sep* in the rqt_reconfigure panel, and I cannot find this section. Did I miss something in previous tutorial which leaded to this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/233893/question-related-to-the-teb-local-planner-tutorial/) by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2016-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [samping](https://answers.ros.org/users/26715/samping/) on 2016-05-08**:
And I check the cfg file for it, I has shown that it contain global_plan_viapoint_sep, but some how it does not show in the panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi samping,

you are not seeing the parameter since the current version on the official ROS repositories (indigo+jade) is 0.3.1.
The path following feature was introduced in Version 0.4 (as noted in the to the API description [here](http://wiki.ros.org/teb_local_planner#Parameters) or in the tutorial).

You can check the current version status [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=teb_local_planner) (indigo) or [here](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_indigo_default.html?q=teb_local_planner) (jade). The third rectangle corresponds to the status for the public repository.

It often takes a couple of weeks until new packages are being synchronized in ROS.
However, you can either checkout the code from [github](https://github.com/rst-tu-dortmund/teb_local_planner) and compile it by yourself, or you can install the pre-released version of the package from the [shadow-fixed repository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository).

---

Originally posted by [croesmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/12166/croesmann/) with karma: 2531 on 2016-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1